# Is it possible to add iframe button that opens modal popup form component from your site?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

For example, on my site I have a button that opens a modal popup with form and I want to add a button to using an iframe to open this form on other sites

The content from iframe should be in full width and height of the screen with a transparent background, but it turns out that it overlaps the content of another site and takes away the ability to interact with content of another site

Comment: content of the iframe is not going to go outside of it.

Comment: Seems quite hacky. What is the exact use case for such usage?